# Is there a symbol in SQL to return "All"

Tags: php, mysql, search

I'm trying to create a search code for my program I'm writing in **PHP** and I am trying to figure out a good way to make my code more compact.  I learned **PHP** from watching YouTube so give me a break ;).

Here is what I started with:

```
if (empty($_POST['nick-cc'])) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pcr WHERE student = $user->id";
} else {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pcr WHERE student = $user->id AND cc = '%$nccn%'";
}
```

The "if" statement would have to be repeated for each column in my database.  So I got to thinking, why can't I use the "*" from the beginning of the SQL in the field to show that if there is no search typed in that it will just return everything instead.  That way if someone comes to the page or just doesn't type anything in and clicks "search" that it will still search but it will search for * (all) but if they do type something in then it will search for that instead.  So this is what I came up with.

But needless to say is not working for me.  Is this a wild goose chase?  Is there a better way?

```
if (empty($_POST['nick-cc'])) {
$nccn = '*';
} else {
$nccn = ''.$_POST['nick-cc'].'';
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pcr WHERE student = $user->id AND cc = '%$nccn%'";
```

Comment: What is this `$nccn`? Also, are we searching using POST? i.e is `$_POST['nick-cc']` the search field?

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to change the $nccn to $_POST['nick-cc'].  and yes all of this is in POST.

Comment: I think `nick-cc`is not a valid variable name. It should be `nick_cc` instead or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really see any reason to make your search more complicated. I usually just append the `LIKE` clause like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pcr WHERE student = $user->id";

if($_POST['nick-cc'] !== ''){
    $sql .= " AND cc = '%$nccn%'";
}
```

More importantly you are vulnerable to sql injection using this method. I would advise you to research parameterized queries and prepared statements. Below is a simple code example using the built in `Mysqli` class.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM pcr WHERE student = ?';
$mysqli = new Mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);
if($_POST['nick-cc'] === ''){
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    if($stmt === false){
        // there was an error
    }

    $stmt->bind_param('i', $user->id);
}else{
    $sql .= ' AND cc = ?';
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    if($stmt === false){
        // there was an error
    }

    $stmt->bind_param('is', $user->id, '%' . $_POST['nick-cc'] . '%');
}

$stmt->execute(); // returns true or false
var_dump($stmt->fetch_array()); // return the results
```

Comment: This is true.  I hadn't thought of this!  This would be perfect!  I will look into parameterized queries also and see if I can figure it out :)

Comment: @JessePfieffer i edited the post to include an example, but there might be some typos

Comment: @JessePfieffer i tested the code on my machine, and i only get sql errors so it should be good now

Comment: I really do appreciate it :).  Im always trying to learn better and safer ways and this is both!

Comment: @JessePfieffer no problem

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just try this:

```
if (empty($_POST['nick-cc'])) {
$nccn = NULL;
} else {
$nccn =  ' AND cc =  %'.$_POST['nick-cc'].'%';
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pcr WHERE student = $user->id $nccn";
```